# How to change woocommerce customer details labels in email?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have changed the customer details label for customer notes but it does not change the label in the "new order" email. How can I change this?

Here is how I changed the way it appears on the invoice page after order is submitted:

```
<header><h2><?php _e( 'Customer Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2></header>

<table class="shop_table customer_details">
<?php if ( $order->customer_note ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php _e( 'Requested Dates:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo wptexturize( $order->customer_note ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This does nothing to the email. Here is a screenshot of how it appears in the email:

[image: I want this to cay "Requested Dates" instead of "Note"]

I found this code in the email-customer-details.php file:

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Customer details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $fields as $field ) : ?>
    <li><strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ); ?>: </strong> 
<span class="text"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $field['value'] );    ?></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

It might help to figure this problem out.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter [`woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L475) which is the array of info passed to the `email-customer-details.php` template.

```
function so_41986388_email_customer_details_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ){
    if( isset( $fields['customer_note'] ) ) {
        $fields['customer_note']['label'] = __( 'Requested Dates:', 'your-text-domain' );
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'so_41986388_email_customer_details_fields', 10, 3 );
```